# Ember controller to fetch data from its model, only upon request. How?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Using ember-data, currently I'm loading data into the controller, on page load, as follows:

```
App.articlesController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: App.store.findAll(App.Article)
});
```

Having a lot of controllers, this would result to a lot of requests. I would like to be able to fetch data from the server only when the controller is requested. Can you suggest, what is the "proper" way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zack,

Have you looked at `didInsertElement` and `willInsertElement`? They will be called when a view did get put into the DOM or will get put into the DOM (respectively). I don't think you need to use `init` here and you shouldn't unless you have to.

Another note: hardcoding references to controllers in your views isn't best either. You should have a binding in your handlebars template. For example if your handlebars template has this:

`{{#view App.ArticlesView controllerBinding="App.articlesController"}}`

your view could then be something like:

```
App.ArticlesView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'app_templates_layouts_articles',

  willInsertElement: function() {
    var controller = this.get('controller');

    if (controller && controller.get && controller.get('content') == null) {
      controller.refresh();
    }
  } 
});
```

That way if you ever need to reuse that view you can easily.

Comment: Thanks, for the useful tip also! I wish there was more of these best practices, I would pay for it.

Comment: I'm working on that with a member of the core team. Not quite sure how this will be presented (i.e. blog posts, something like the Ruby/Sproutcore Guides, etc) but it will be free. :)

Answer (score 1):

you could initially set the content to an empty array and have a load method which can be called as you like:

```
App.articlesController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: []

    load: function() {
        this.set("content", App.store.findAll(App.Article));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that if you define a method as `init` it gets called upon creation of the object.

So I define an `init` function within the associated view, that checks if data was fetched:

```
App.ArticlesView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'app_templates_layouts_articles',

  init: function() {
    this._super();

    if ( App.articlesController.get("content") == null){
      App.articlesController.refresh();
    }
  } 
});
```